# Как указать на соседний элемент Data Grid в C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как можно указать в коде на соседнюю ячейку в Data Grid без придания ей собственного имени (сверху или снизу)? Возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: У вас должна быть коллекция, с которой вы должны работать. Забудьте в WPF про контролы, UI, это там неуместно! Делаете коллекцию с данными, задаете `DataContext` окну на класс, где эта коллекция находится, в XAML привязываете то, что надо (`<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding коллекция}"/>`), все, у вас отдельно живет UI и отдельно живут данные, делайте теперь в коде что хотите с той коллекцией, ищите то, что хотите и как хотите.

Comment: Поищите по ключевым словам `WPF MVVM DataGrid binding`. Ваш вопрос связан с неверным подходом к работе с данными в WPF, он сложный и непопулярный. В связи с этим вряд-ли вы получите прямой ответ здесь.

Comment: Если же вы хотите придти к верному решению, покажите весь код и разметку, расскажите, что делает ваше приложение, и какую именно задачу вы хотите решить. Отредактируйте вопрос. Затем напишите мне комментарий, отметив меня в нем: @aepot. Тогда я смогу дать ответ.